# Intercept incoming call ios sdk (Non Jailbreak)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, call

Hi i have tried for bundle of times and find out that iOS SDK does not give us access due to security reasons for getting following data;

**Intercept an incoming call** (Getting phone number from incoming call)

**Read Call history**

**Intercept SMS** (Getting phone number from incoming SMS and reading its contents)

**Block an incoming call**
etc

Here are some of the links resulting from my search about this issue:-

[How can I get the callers phone number from an incoming call on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739424/how-can-i-get-the-callers-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call-on-iphone)

http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

[Programmatically get the number of the incoming call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003791/programmatically-get-the-number-of-the-incoming-call)

[Can I fetch details of the incoming call phone number in my applicaton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817456/can-i-fetch-details-of-the-incoming-call-phone-number-in-my-applicaton?rq=1)

[Hook into incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417658/hook-into-incomming-call?rq=1)

[handling an incoming call through an app in iphone xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357950/handling-an-incoming-call-through-an-app-in-iphone-xcode?rq=1)

[Identify number of incoming call in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992368/identify-number-of-incoming-call-in-iphone?rq=1)

I also found that [CoreTelephony CTCall object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590) provide us only limited info, Just call state and its unique Id. But nothing else we can get by using CoreTelephony framework.

**But, I have seen one application on app store that does gets incoming call phone number.**

I wonder how this app
[Callinize iPone App](https://itunes.apple.com/hk/app/callinize/id654644710?mt=8)
works and gets incoming call info?

**I also want the same thing to do with my app. But i did't find such a way to do. Please help if you can.**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the description of the app you linked us to? It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: So what it does @Luke

Comment: Yes, i have read that description. But confusing thing for me is this line of description "Callinize is an app that works with your office phone system to detect inbound calls, it then connects to your company's CRM, pulls relevant info, and displays this information for all incoming calls on your mobile phone. During the call you can launch into our app and save call notes."

Comment: Hmm a little bit confusing statement @iosDev

Comment: @Luke-- Means. How the app detects that incoming call is from a specific contact for that the app gets its info from CRM? Have you some idea about that? If you have then please share.

Comment: @GaganKumar-- Yes, its confusing.

Comment: Some offices use call manager software to track incoming and outbound calls. Some call manager software will allow for calls to be forwarded from an employee's desk phone to their mobile, for example. In this situation, the software knows who is calling and who they are trying to reach. They can lookup the caller ID and obtain any information about the caller from their database. This information can be sent as a push notification to the user's mobile, whilst the call is redirected. This is but one possible way they are doing it - but they are not using any CoreTelephony methods to do this.

Comment: @Luke-- Hmmm, Agree with you. May be they have adopted the same strategy as you have pointed out. Anyhow, Thanks for your reply and comments.

Comment: Intercept an incoming call (Getting phone number from incoming call) can you get also the phone number that is being called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm late to the party here, but I was just reading the description of Callinize. They built an integration with the Asterix pbx system and it only works with Asterix. So this app does not really access iOS phone calls.

Comment: @Jared-- Yeah, That may be possible.