# How to hear music while end phone call in IOS

Tags: ios, phone-call

I want to do the following task:

**Make a call to someone after they pick up the phone, the application play a sound from my phone after it finished the application will close the call.**

Is it possible or not in `iOS` ?
I need some help.

Thank for any help.

Comment: How about jailbroken device ?
Is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user receives call, speaker and audio hardwares are grabbed by OS from apps using them and suspend those apps. So, it's not possible to get audio hardware from OS while user has stablished call connection.

Answer (score 2):

Two Words From `Apple`.

Not Possible

Case 2 : Jailbreak Device.
Not Very Much Idea about it [please review this lin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119474/intercept-incoming-call-ios-sdk-non-jailbreak)k

Comment: Is it possible,
If device jailbroken ?

Comment: @chabsiheng I think It is not possible in JailBroken device too. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Till now it is
    "NOT POSSIBLE"

Answer (score 0):

**No this feature is not available yet.**

Answer (score 0):

No it's **not possible** in IOS. I think, it's `not possible` even in **Jailbroken device too**. See [all link in this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119474/intercept-incoming-call-ios-sdk-non-jailbreak).